# What role/permission I need in order to assume role of child account using boto3 and python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

So as mentioned in the title I need to assume role of one of my child accounts using boto3 and python. I am making a request from the master account and with an IAM user cause as I read a root account can not assume role, only user. So the user is created, has admin permissions and I have also created a custom policy, here is the JSON:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I keep getting:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied

Btw, here is my code:

```
sts = boto3.client('sts')
response = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:organizations::123456789:account/Master',
    RoleSessionName='currentSession'
)
```

And yes, I have credentials and config set locally.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'child' account, you will need:

- An **IAM Role** that you wish to assume
- A **Trust Relationship** on the role that permits the other account to use it
- A policy that gives access to the resources you want the role to use

In the 'parent' account, you will need:

- An IAM User that has `sts:AssumeRole` permission for, at minimum, the IAM Role in the child account

By the way, the concept of 'child' or 'master' account is not necessary. It's just one account calling `AssumeRole` on a role in another account.

Based on the error message you are receiving, the IAM User that you are using to call `AssumeRole` does not have the necessary permissions. So, either the IAM User that the program is using does *not* have the policy you have shown, or **the IAM Role that it is attempting to assume in the other account does not have a trust relationship** that permits the request from the 'child' account.

See: [Creating a Role to Delegate Permissions to an IAM User - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html)

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase my question then, is it possible to assume role of a child account from an IAM user from a master account by only knowing the child account arn and id using only boto3 and python?

Comment: Yes, if the permissions have been correctly configured.

Comment: By permission being correctly configured you mean to add the previously mentioned permissions in both master and child account, right?